# ADF: data set Row deliminater multiple characters

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using azure data factory to parse a .dat file.

Each row is being delimited by a string 'TASK'.

### Example

TRY 1*2*3 ~ 9*4*6 TASK 34T*89YT*56 TASK 36*890*5T67 TASK 365*890PT6*5678

---

When I do a data preview a separate row is shown every time there is a character 'T'.
Is there a way to use a  row delimiter with a string value?

In the example above I need three separate rows that start with the string 'TASK'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For Copy activity, the single character or "\r\n" used to separate rows in a file.

[image]

**Image Reference:** MS document on [Delimited text properties in ADF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-delimited-text#dataset-properties).

Only single character can be used as row delimiter. That is the reason, it takes `T` as the delimitter even when `TASK` is given as delimiter.  you cannot read the file with delimitter as `TASK` using copy activity. This can be achieved using mapping dataflow transformation activity. Below are the steps,

- Take the **Source transformation** with source dataset. Give the row delimiter as `\n` and column delimiter as  `,`. These delimiters are chosen because these delimiters are not part of data.
  [image]
- Take the **derived column transformation** and give the expression for the column as `split(Column_1,'TASK')`.

[image]
This will make the array of values from `column1` data.

- Take the **flatten transformation** and give the value for `unroll by` as `column1` array.

[image]

**Output of flatten transformation:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks much Aswin for this. I think this approach will work good, only thing is I need the TRY row to be a  Header row and have a separate sink.  All the rest of the rows (With TASK) are data rows and will need to be in a different sink. How do I separate them?

Comment: If you want to split this into two file, you can use [conitional-split-transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-flow-conditional-split) and give the condition in such a way that it divides into two files and then use two sinks for each part of conditional -split transformation

Comment: So use the conditional split after your flatten1 step?  
How will I specify in the conditional split to take the first row from flatten1 activity as a header and rest of the rows go to the  data? What will go in the condition ?

Comment: Yes..you can give after **flatten transformation**. Give the condition in such a way ..it takes only try row in one part and all others in other part.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to see, what to add to the expression builder to look for the "Try" row.  This is what I have for Header stream = locate(Column_1,'TRY')>0..
Not sure if Column_1 is correct there though.

Comment: `like(Column_1,'TRY%')` this expression may help you to identify header row

Comment: That worked like a charm!! Thank you so much Aswin.